# Can't use a global variable from JS with AJAX call in other script element on same html page

Tags: javascript, ajax, global-variables, undefined

I've been looking around as to how to use a variable from one script on a page and use it in another script. I've found that you can set your variable to global (although this is not preferred, but I havn't found a better way).

I am using the Bootstrap framework.

On my page, I have an AJAX call in a function. I have declared the variable in front on the function so that it is a global variable. The value of the variable is set in the success function of the AJAX call.

In another script (inside a modal) I then use the variable to output as text. This works when I set the value of the variable outside the AJAX function, but it gives value='undefined' when the value is set in the AJAX success.

The modal in which the variable is used is only opened after the AJAX success function, but maybe the value is already read before the AJAX request, even when the modal is not shown? Is there a way to say that it only has to be loaded after the AJAX success function?

This is an abstract of my code for the AJAX function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var theVariable;
function() {
    //AJAX Call
    $.ajax({
        //Abbreviated
        success: function(data) {
            theVariable = "test";
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the code I use in the modal to read the variable

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = theVariable;
</script>
```

So to recap, when I set the value of theVariable while declaring it (outside of the AJAX function), the value is displayed in the modal. However, when I try to set the value inside the AJAX success function this value is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because `theVariable` is outside the scope of `$.ajax()`.

This should work:

```
var theVariable;
function() {
    var that = this;
    //AJAX Call
    $.ajax({
        //Abbreviated
        success: function(data) {
            that.theVariable = "test";
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In the second script, can I use that.theVariable then? I tested an alert in the ajax success call on theVariable and that is able to read it, so I didn't think it would be outside the scope

Comment: No, you don't need `that.`. You should be able to use `theVariable` as you do now.

Comment: I tried it and it just shows up empty inside the modal, so instead of 'undefined' it now shows nothing. I still think it might have something to do with the modal content somehow being created before the ajax success function.

Comment: It's possible. So you need to find a way to update your modal window content. I can't tell you how to do it, relying on the information you've provided.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was realy helpfull on the ajax scope part. I think i'm going to rewrite my code so that the content of the modal is set in the ajax success funtion. That way I'm sure the variable is available

Comment: It's probably the best way to do it!

Comment: The fix was to change the body of the modal in the AJAX success funtion. Apparently the script in the modal is executed when the page is created (before opening the modal). At that time, the variable to be printed in the modal was still undefined.